# PHP/MySQL targeting only month from date field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table has a date column formatted as yyyy-mm-dd.

Is it possible to have a query that only lists results found for any day in a specific month? There could be any month of any year in this table, but say i want to list them for only june 2013?

Thanks

Comment: I would feel better about giving you help if you tried something first.

Comment: What data type is the field? Is it a string, that you have inserted as `yyyy-mm-dd` or is it a DateTime that is simply displaying as `yyyy-mm-dd`? MySql has String functions that you could use to get the two characters in the mm slot. Check out the substring function.

Comment: @Daedalus i wasnt aware this site was off limits to people who have no idea what they are doing.

Comment: you can also use `WHERE` [`YEAR(date_col) = spec_year`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) `&` [`MONTH(date_col) = spec_month`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Comment: @user2391454 [Read paragraph 2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and I never said it was off limits to that group of people; don't put words in my mouth; I simply said I'd feel better if you tried something first.

Comment: I think you should both calm down. @user2391454 The FAQ states that you should do your best to show what you have tried so far. If you are so lost that you can't produce any code, then you should clearly explain what hangups you are having in understanding where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date_column_name LIKE '2013-06%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where date_column between '2013-06-01' and '2013-06-30'
```